# Using the GeoJSON API

Tags: griddb

the problem is when i write the code it shows me this message error :
Exception has occurred: JSONDecodeError
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
StopIteration: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\LapTop\Desktop\haystuck.py\main.py", line 13, in 
json_obj = json.loads(data)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
I didn't try anything because i reallyy have no idea about it[A screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI3G9.png)

Comment: Please post code not pictures of code. But judging from the error message, `data` is not valid JSON. Check its contents

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)